# neo4j taking lots of virtual memory

Tags: performance, neo4j, virtual-memory

I've noticed that the neo4j server process is taking 11gb of virtual memory. (2.3M2)

This happened while i was tuning a query, and i thought, that it was the cause for the slow performance

then, I've created a new Virtual machine with a new instance of neo4j server, and it was the same.

here is a screenshot from the first server:

[image: htop from a server , running heavy query]

also, are all the processes opened above valid (all of them are child processes but 1)

Comment: did anything helped you in this case at all?